# How to check integer and string in c:if in jsf?

Tags: jsf, jstl

I have two bean values one is Integer and other is string i want to check for equality how to do so in jsf?

My code is as below

```
<c:if test="#{item.asString eq items.asInt}">
   <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"></h:outputText>
</c:if>
```

Now for all condition the codition is checked true please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the body of `<c:set>` to convert any object to string (note: using `<c:set value>` as posted by [popovitsj's currently edited and deleted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT560.png) **will not** work!)

```
<c:set var="intAsString">#{items.asInt}</c:set>
<c:if test="#{item.asString eq intAsString}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
</c:if>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, unless the condition is only available during view build time, you normally use JSF component's `rendered` attribute to conditionally render JSF components:

```
<c:set var="intAsString">#{items.asInt}</c:set>
<h:outputText value="#{item.name}" rendered="#{item.asString eq intAsString}" />
```